# How to get device id for google cloud messenger push notification

Tags: android, push-notification

Im following some tutorial to do push notification, and reading from the google documentation also. the part to register client app to get the registration id somehow not working, its too much part that i don't need.

I finished the web interface part, to send the push notification from web page.

is there some step by step to make it easier to understand? and is there snippet to get the registration id only?

Answer (score 0):

After you setup the project in the FCM Console, and in your Android Studio Project when you run your app the registration happes on its own behind the scenes.

When the device gets registered you get a callback onTokenRefresh() in the service you have to implement that extends FirebaseInstanceIdService. After that you can get the token by calling FirebaseInstanceID.getToken().